# How to delete the last string in an array of char with strtok in C?

Tags: c, arrays, strtok

I have a function which accepts some values as `char array[]` parameters.

These values are separated with semicolons (`';'`).

For example: `"hello;dear;John"`

So I'm trying to figure out a way by using `strtok` to delete the last string, which is `"John"` after the last semicolon.

```
int remove(char lastName[]){


}
```

*To be more specific

I have created this function which removes values separated by semicolons:

```
int remove(char variable_Name[]){

        char *value_toRemove = getenv(variable_Name);
        char last_semicolon[] = ";";
        char *result = NULL;
        result = strtok( value_toRemove, last_semicolon );
        while( result != NULL ) {
        result = strtok( NULL, last_semicolon );
        }
        return NULL;    
}
```

But the function deletes everything after it finds a semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strrchr` will find the last occurance of the character.

Sor if you don't mind modifyint the original string then it should be as simple as

```
int remove(char *lastName){
   char *pos = strrchr(lastName, ';');
   if (pos) {
      *pos = 0;
      return pos-lastName;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Man Page [here](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strrchr/)

Comment: can you please tell me what *pos = 0; return pos-lastName; do?

Comment: It returns the length of the new truncated string by simply calculating the difference between the pointer of the start of the string (lastName) and the position we have zeroed (pos) .. the subtraction of the two pointers gives the number of bytes between them.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *last_semi = strrchr(lastName, ';');

if (last_semi != NULL)
   *last_semi = '\0';
```

**EDIT:** In response to your comment, it does work. This is how I'd do it and I've included the whole program to show an example of the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *remove_end(char *str, char c)
{
   char *last_pos = strrchr(str, c);

   if (last_pos != NULL) {
      *last_pos = '\0';
      return last_pos + 1; /* pointer to the removed part of the string */
   }

   return NULL;  /* c wasn't found in the string */
}

int main(void)
{
   char s1[] = "hello;dear;John";
   char s2[] = "nothing to remove";
   char *removed;

   /* s1 */
   printf("Original string: %s\n", s1);
   removed = remove_end(s1, ';');
   printf("New string: %s\n", s1);
   printf("Removed: %s\n", removed ? removed : "NOTHING");
   /* s2 */
   printf("Original string: %s\n", s2);
   removed = remove_end(s2, ';');
   printf("New string: %s\n", s2);
   printf("Removed: %s\n", removed ? removed : "NOTHING");

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Original string: hello;dear;John
New string: hello;dear
Removed: John
Original string: nothing to remove
New string: nothing to remove
Removed: NOTHING
```

You can also try it live [here](http://ideone.com/KVV04).

Comment: ty for the quick answer m8. I would also want to ask you what should my function return?

Comment: @user1031654 I would probably return 0 (ie. FALSE) if `last_semi` was `NULL` (`';'` wasn't found in the string), and 1 (ie. TRUE) or any other non-zero value to indicate that `';'` was found and replaced with a `'\0'`. Perhaps even a `char *` to the end of the string that's been cut off. If it's not important to you then you could just make the function's return type `void`.

Comment: unfortunately it does not seems to work :/ Is there a way to do it with strtok?

Comment: @user1031654 It does work, I've edited my answer with the whole function to show.

Comment: I've modified your code to accept input from stdin to allow changing the input without modifying the code. http://ideone.com/dYN5j

Comment: I have given you an example of what i am trying to do with this function. And ty a lot for the code example that you posted :)